# SAS check if value is in dynamic list of variables

Tags: list, sas

I want to check if a character variable is present in 9 other character variables, but I struggle writing a piece of code that can automatically generate a list of variables for each observation in my dataset. Here's an example of the dataset that I have:

```
| ID | MainVar | Var1   | Var2 | Var3   | Var4 | Var5 | Var6| Var7 | Var8 | Var9 |
| 1  | Apple   | Orange | Pear |        |      |      |     |      |      |      |
| 2  | Pear    | Apple  | Pear | Orange |      |      |     |      |      |      |
```

I would like to output a flag or something similar for ID 1, which does not have MainVar present in Var1-9. So looking something like this:

```
| ID | MainVar | Var1   | Var2 | Var3   | Var4 | Var5 | Var6| Var7 | Var8 | Var9 | Err_msg    |
| 1  | Apple   | Orange | Pear |        |      |      |     |      |      |      | Check list |
| 2  | Pear    | Apple  | Pear | Orange |      |      |     |      |      |      |            |
```

My code looks like this:

```
Data Want; 
    set have; 

    if MainVar not in (Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6, Var7, Var8, Var9) then Err_msg = 'Check list';
run;
```

SAS generated the following error:

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
              a missing value, iterator, (.
```

I assume I need to generate an actual liste of quoted strings, even though all the VAR1-9 variables are indeed character strings. Does anyone have an easy fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to come up with a solution myself.

```
Data want;
     set have; 

     array list Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9;
     if MainVar not in list then Err_Msg = 'Check list';

run;
```

Seems pretty simple and works quite all right.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the WHICHx function.  If MAINVAR and VAR1-VAR9 are character use WHICHC() and if they are numeric use WHICHN.  This will also allow you to use variable lists.

```
data want;
 set have; 
 if not whichc(mainvar, of var1-var9) then Err_Msg = 'Check list';
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

On way would be to concatenate all the `var` variables into a string, and use `index`

```
  length allvars $1000. ; 
  allvars = catx('|', of Var:) ; 
  if index(allvars,strip(MainVar)) = 0 then ErrMsg = 'Check list' ;
```

Comment: I suppose that would work, so thanks for the input. I managed to find a solution myself before seeing your response.